# Why not synchronized?

Tags: java, synchronized

About Java synchronized, I try an example (from TLF-SOFT-VTC.java.6CFE), but it turns out wrong, why doesn't it synchronized ? The code :

```
public class InterferenceFix extends Thread {
    String name;
    static boolean isZero = true;
    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        InterferenceFix one = new InterferenceFix("one");
        InterferenceFix two = new InterferenceFix("two");
        one.start();
        two.start();
    }

    InterferenceFix(String nameString) {
        name = nameString;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            update();
        }
        System.out.println(name + ": " + counter);
    }

    synchronized void update() {
        if (isZero) {
            isZero = false;
            counter++;
        } else {
            isZero = true;
            counter--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to label `run()` with the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Also: floss daily, and look both ways before crossing the street.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only your `update` method is synchronized which means that the loop can run simultaneously on both threads, only the `update` itself can't.

Also - the `synchronized` keyword actually locks on the object `this` and in your case, we're talking about 2 different instances which means they lock on different `this`. This means that actively - the threads are not interfering in any way with each other's work and they can both run simultaneously.

If that's indeed what you want you'd probably be better creating a static lock:

```
private static final Object lock = new lock();
```

And change `update` (or run) to this:

```
void update() {
     synchronized (lock) {
        if (isZero) {
             isZero = false;
             counter++;
        } else {
             isZero = true;
             counter--;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to sync the for loop, just use the lock in the same manner around the loop instead of inside `update`.

Comment: `update()` can run simultaneously on both threads too; there's absolutely nothing stopping them as the two threads are synchronizing on different objects.

Comment: Thank you all, according to what you said, I add a 'static' before the method update(), it works.

Answer (score 4):

`synchronized` on an instance method does just serialize calls per instance, `synchronized` on a static method would do that per class, hence for all calls. So they have different lock objects. As one can guess now, a `static synchronized` method may be used to modify those static fields.